# AngularJS: How to properly update data in a service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

There's no problem with populating a service (factory actually) with asynchronous data. However, what is the proper way of updating data in a service?

The problem that I run into is that all async data is access with `.then()` method, basically a promise resolve. Now, how would I put something into a service, and update related views?

The service I'm using:

```
function ($q) {
    var _data = null;
    return {
        query: function (expire) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if (_data) {
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                $http.get('/path').then(function (response) {
                    defer.resolve(response.data);
                });
            }
            return defer.promise;
        }
        ,
        byId: function(id) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            this.query().then(function(data){
                angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
                    if (item.id == id) {
                        return defer.resolve(item);
                    }
                });
                return defer.reject('id not found');
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
        ,
        add: function(item) {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

What would be good implementation of `add` method? Note, that I'm working with `Angular >1.2`

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a few examples to show ways to get data from your service into your controllers and thereby allow the data to be bound in the views.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ABQsAxz1bNi34ehmPRsF?p=preview

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.4" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>   </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{sharedData.label}}
      <br>
      <input type="text"  ng-model="sharedData.label"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="sharedData.label"/>
      <button ng-click="updateValue()">test</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl3">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="sharedData.label"/>
      <button ng-click="updateValue()">test</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl4">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="sharedData.label"/>
    </div>
       </body>

</html>
```

The JS

```
angular.module("myApp", []).service("MyService", function($q) {
  var serviceDef = {};
  //It's important that you use an object or an array here a string or other
  //primitive type can't be updated with angular.copy and changes to those
  //primitives can't be watched.
  serviceDef.someServiceData = {
    label: 'aValue'
  };
  serviceDef.doSomething = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    angular.copy({
      label: 'an updated value'
    }, serviceDef.someServiceData);

    deferred.resolve(serviceDef.someServiceData);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return serviceDef;
}).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, MyService) {
  //Using a data object from the service that has it's properties updated async
  $scope.sharedData = MyService.someServiceData;
}).controller("MyCtrl2", function($scope, MyService) {
  //Same as above just has a function to modify the value as well
  $scope.sharedData = MyService.someServiceData;
  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    MyService.doSomething();
  }
}).controller("MyCtrl3", function($scope, MyService) {
  //Shows using a watch to see if the service data has changed during a digest
  //if so updates the local scope
  $scope.$watch(function(){ return MyService.someServiceData }, function(newVal){
    $scope.sharedData = newVal;
  })
  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    MyService.doSomething();
  }
}).controller("MyCtrl4", function($scope, MyService) {
  //This option relies on the promise returned from the service to update the local
  //scope, also since the properties of the object are being updated not the object
  //itself this still stays "in sync" with the other controllers and service since
  //really they are all referring to the same object.
  MyService.doSomething().then(function(newVal) {
    $scope.sharedData = newVal;
  });
});
```

Regarding the add method in the service you'd want it to do something similar to a get, just create a deferred that you return the promise from and then do your async business (http request).  For your byId function you may want to use a cached version (save the data that comes back from the query call in a property of the service).  This way the query doesn't need to be executed every time if that's not necessary.

Comment: Actually, I already am caching the backend calls in real life scenario. :) Then, deferrals for everything. Will give it a go. However, it is the first idea I had myself, just it seemed "wrong".